# Differect Result with Replace method in Python

Tags: python, methods, replace, logic

**Context :**
I'm writing a program to find 1st non-repeating letter in a string.

***TEST CODE***
I need to implement following logic :

```
s = "iiiiiiitya"
if 'i' in s:
    s = s.replace('i','')
print(s)
```

**OUTPUT :** tya

Which is fine. **It removes all the occurances of 'i' from the string.** That is what I wanted.

**PROBLEM :** But as soon as I start to implement same logic in my actual program, the function doesn't work the same i.e. It only removes only 1st occurance of the perticulare letter and hence my logic fails.

```
def non_rep(s):
    for el in s:
        if el in s[1:]:
            s = s.replace(el,'')
        else:
            return el
    return "No such case is matched"
str = "adiiiityda"
ch = non_rep(str)
print(ch)
```

**OUTPUT :** i

**EXPECTED OUTPUT :** t

Why does it behave in such way, I tried a lot, but it works like it should in the first(test) code and when I implement it into program it behave differently.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? It modifies the string as it iterates over it, leading to unexpected behaviour. Also why `s[1:]`?

Comment: what is expected input & output?

Comment: You should not loop over the characters and apply a transform on the whole string at each step. This is very inefficient (you read n^2 characters for a string of length n). Instead count first the characters, then list the unique ones in order (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69550644/16343464))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to get the counts, then keep only the unique values:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "iiiiiiitya"

c = Counter(s)
''.join([i for i in c if c[i]==1])
```

output: `tya`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function count on strings in Python as the following:

```python
def non_rep(s):
    for char in s:
        if s.count(char) == 1:
            return char
```

Comment: This is not efficient as you need to read the string again for each character O(n^2)

Comment: No, but it is similar to the original code. There, the user was attempting to scan the string forward for each character, as well as made use of the replace function which is O(n). The user did not request the most optimal solution - he asked to fix the problems with his code.

Answer (score 1):

The following implements your idea using `while` instead:

```py
def non_rep(s):
    while s: # while s is non-empty
        el = s[0] # get the first character
        if el in s[1:]: # if the character is found in another place
            s = s.replace(el, '') # remove all of them
        else: # if not repeated
            return s[0] # return that
    return 'No such case is matched' # this is reached when depleted

print(non_rep("adiiiityda")) # t
print(non_rep("aabbcc")) # No such case is matched
```

It is generally advised *not* to remove an item in a `for` loop. If you put `print(el, s)` right after `for el in s:`, you would see what is happening. You would find out that `el` just follows the *original* string `adiiiityda`. So at the fourth iteration, `el` is `'i'` while `s` is `'ty'`. Your code cannot find this `'i'` in `'ty'`, so it returns `'i'`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that string is immutable, hence you can not change it on loop it won't behave the way you want:

```
def non_rep(s):
    for el in s:
        if el in s[1:]:
            s = s.replace(el,'')
    if len(s)>0:
        return s[0]
    return "No such case is matched"

str = "adiiiityda"
ch = non_rep(str)
print(ch)
```